# Batch : How To open Excel workbook in an existing opend excel session

Tags: excel, batch-file, session

At my job I have commands that open many Excel Wrokbooks in different excel sessions each morning. I cannot modify these .cmd files. These Excel Workbooks
have all the same name "C.xlsb", but if you go to the first sheet of each one and look at P11 you will notice that they are not the same.

I want to write a batch code that selects a "C.xlsb" workbook that is opened that I want and in its session open another workbook called "I.xlsm"

So far I have the following that is opening the file I want, but it is opening the file in a session of excel that is not in the one I want.

How can I select the specific excel session to open my workbook in it?

```
"\\nas0013\pub$\E\I\I.xlsm"
exit /B
```